# How to bind 80 non-root

Tags: macos, http, nginx, apache2

Is there anyway to bind a program on Mac OS to :80 without root privilege, like on Linux for exemple having user www to be able to do so.

Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: No, it can not be done on Linux either. A process binding to a port <= 1024 calls `bind()` as root and switches its effective UID, e.g. to "www", later. For ideas how to fiddle with port 80 while your process sits waiting on a port > 1024, see [this question in Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37418/how-can-i-open-port-80-so-a-non-root-process-can-bind-to-it).

Comment: That's not true, on linux you can set CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE with `sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/local/bin/node`. Unfortunately OS X doesn't recognise this option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your concern that you don't want nginx running as root or that you don't have root access?

Nginx has a [`user`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#user) config option which will drop root after binding to the port.

If you don't have root access the best solution I know of on OS X is to use [pf](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/filter.html#syntax) to setup ip redirection to a non-priviliged port, however you'll still need to get someone with root access to do this.

The config for pf is stored in /etc/pf.conf - I believe that you can simply add rules to this file and reload pf for them to take effect.

```
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8081
```

Then reload pf with `sudo pfctl -F all -ef /etc/pf.conf` and configure nginx to listen on the ports to redirected to.

Comment: Yes I'm concern about running nginx as root and I do have root access, well the first solution works for me I set user to _www , still the master process runs as root but I guess that one cannot be stopped while using nginx.


ps aux : 

_www             1614   0,0  0,0  2464100   1008   ??  S    10:48     0:00.00 nginx: worker process  


root             1613   0,0  0,0  2463880   2516   ??  Ss   10:48     0:00.01 nginx: master process /usr/local/opt/nginx/bin/nginx -g daemon off;